# Unity3d - Load a specific scene on play mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

Ok, so I'm working on a small project that has a main menu and 10 levels. From time to time I edit different levels, and want to try them out, however I get a `NullPointerException` as my levels rely on certain variables from the main menu for the levels to work, which means I have to alter my levels, then load my main menu and play from there.

Is there something that can be done in the Unity Editor to default load a specific scene when you hit Play, and not the scene you're on?

I could obviously resolve this to something like

```
public bool goToMenu; //set this to true in my levels through inspector

Start()
{
    if (goToMenu)
        //then load main menu
}
```

but it would be really handy if there was a way to set the default level to load when hitting play mode. I've had a look in Preferences but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: You could take a look at this: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SceneAutoLoader. I've not used it myself, but it sounds like it may be of some help.

Comment: That is a incredibly outdated approach, do NOT do that.  if you MUST tackle this issue, which you should not, just use the "script execution order" trick mentioned below.

Comment: YES : EditorSceneManager.playModeStartScene

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I made this simple script that loads the scene at index 0 in the build settings when you push Play. I hope someone find it useful.

It detects when the play button is push and load the scene. Then, everything comes back to normal.

Oh! And it automatically executes itself after opening Unity and after compile scripts, so never mind about execute it. Simply put it on a Editor folder and it works.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

[InitializeOnLoadAttribute]
public static class DefaultSceneLoader
{
    static DefaultSceneLoader(){
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += LoadDefaultScene;
    }

    static void LoadDefaultScene(PlayModeStateChange state){
        if (state == PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode) {
            EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo ();
        }

        if (state == PlayModeStateChange.EnteredPlayMode) {
            EditorSceneManager.LoadScene (0);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Automatic Editor plugin seems to be a proper way to do this.

Comment: To make it more specific, this goes into Assets/Editor/something.cs. Because it is 'an Editor plugin'.

Comment: For the future search engine user: This works out of the box in unity 2022.1.x. I did not have to put it into an Editor folder.

Comment: This unfortunately still loads the scene you are on and then instantly changes to the first scene. The problem with this approach is that the scene that might be open will throw a lot of errors because it's not supposed to be the first loaded scene.

Comment: Still working on the 2022.3.2f1 version. Yes, it's first loading the current scene and shows tons of errors because -in most cases- it's not supposed to be the first loaded scene. But after loading the scene, all errors will disappear from the console.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way is to set your 0th scene as the default play mode scene:

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class EditorInit
{
    static EditorInit()
    {
        var pathOfFirstScene = EditorBuildSettings.scenes[0].path;
        var sceneAsset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<SceneAsset>(pathOfFirstScene);
        EditorSceneManager.playModeStartScene = sceneAsset;
        Debug.Log(pathOfFirstScene + " was set as default play mode scene");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, I just placed this in a script in the Editor folder

Comment: How cancel this auto load? Im delete this script but editor load first scene, may be it override playModeStartScene and I will be fix it?

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev probably you need to restart unity

Comment: This is the way to go. It's simpler than the accepted answer, and it doesn't produce the potential error logs, since it doesn't first load the current scene, then switch to the other. Just make sure you add using statements for UnityEngine, UnityEditor, and UnityEditor.SceneManagement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the editor script that I wrote that do exactly what you want.
https://github.com/CSaratakij/SceneSelector
It has the UI to select a specific scene and option to open the first scene in the build setting when enter the playmode.
Might be useful for the future visitor.

Comment: The accepted answer is solving the problem, not necessary to install something more in the project, imho.

Answer (score 0):

i use this in Editor Folder:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;

[InitializeOnLoad]
public class DefaultSceneLoader : EditorWindow
{

    private const string defaultScenePath = "Assets/Scenes/Preload.unity";

    static DefaultSceneLoader()
    {
        EditorApplication.playModeStateChanged += LoadDefaultScene;
    }

    static void LoadDefaultScene(PlayModeStateChange state)
    {
        if (state == PlayModeStateChange.ExitingEditMode)
        {
            if (EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene().path != defaultScenePath)
            {
               
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("dsl_lastPath", EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene().path);
                PlayerPrefs.Save();

                EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo();

                EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>
                {
                    EditorSceneManager.OpenScene(defaultScenePath);
                    EditorApplication.isPlaying = true;
                };

                EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
            }
        }

        if (state == PlayModeStateChange.EnteredEditMode)
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("dsl_lastPath"))
            {
                EditorSceneManager.OpenScene(PlayerPrefs.GetString("dsl_lastPath"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a well-known basic issue in Unity.

There is **no good solution** unfortunately.

When you click "Play" in a game engine it should of course jump to your preload scene and "Play" from there.

Unfortunately in Unity this does not happen.

## Every experienced Unity engineer recommends NOT trying to automate this. But if you must...

```
/* 
ONLY FOR USE DURING DEVELOPMENT IN THE EDITOR
ONLY FOR USE DURING DEVELOPMENT IN THE EDITOR
ONLY FOR USE DURING DEVELOPMENT IN THE EDITOR

MUST RUN FIRST USING "SCRIPT EXECUTION ORDER" system
MUST RUN FIRST USING "SCRIPT EXECUTION ORDER" system
MUST RUN FIRST USING "SCRIPT EXECUTION ORDER" system

YOU MUST REMOVE THIS SCRIPT BEFORE BUILDING TO PRODUCTION
YOU MUST REMOVE THIS SCRIPT BEFORE BUILDING TO PRODUCTION
YOU MUST REMOVE THIS SCRIPT BEFORE BUILDING TO PRODUCTION
*/

using UnityEngine;
public class DevPreload:MonoBehaviour {

    void Awake() {

        GameObject check = GameObject.Find("__app");
        // "__app" is one of your DDOL gameobject in preload scene
        if (check==null)
            SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("_preload");
        }
    
    }
```

The secret is to use

## Unity's Script Execution Order system

Simply **have that script run before anything** and it will do what you want.

HOWEVER - be aware that the Script Execution Order system is an incredibly bad engineering idea which nobody ever uses because it's so flakey.

This "trick" is !!ONLY!! for use during development.  Stay sober!

Comment: In fact, ignore that last comment - I've only just managed to get back on Unity since I asked this question, and I had a look at your link you included in your answer (I think you asked the same question - great minds think alike!) and I used the code that you included in your question from everyone's response - works like a charm!

Comment: Curious - is that code in your question from that link "safe"? Would there be any compile errors or build errors internally?

Comment: Noted, thanks! I'll mark this answer as correct as your code will work too :)

Comment: While I agree with the whole answer, I'd like to point out that "globals in programming" is not a bad thing when you know what you're doing. And in some practical cases, it is even more elegant to use them than avoiding them at all costs. But that's a bit off topic :)

Comment: lol it's funny you mention that incidental issue, @Masadow .  Indeed globals have an important role.  I'm gonna remove my incidental example there.